# Calling a method on every word in an array

Tags: ruby, iteration, each

I am building a Pig Latin translator. I was able to make a method `pig` for a single word using the following code:

```
def pig(str)
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
arr = str.split(//)

  if vowels.include? arr[0]
  result = str + 'ay'
  else
  str.slice!(0)
    if ! vowels.include? arr[1]
    str.slice!(0)
    result = str + arr[0] + arr[1] + 'ay'
    else
    result = str + arr[0] + 'ay'
    end
  end

result
end
```

which functions like this:

```
pig('eat')   # => eatay
pig('apple') # => appleay
pig('pie')   # => iepay
```

I am trying to write another method `translate` so I can enter a string of multiple words, and call the `pig` method on each word in the string. Here is what I tried:

```
def translate(str2)
  words = str2.split(' ')
  words.each do |x|
    pig(x)
  end
end
```

I used this sample code to test the results:

```
puts translate('eat apple pie')
```

Although each individual word was translated successfully, the `translate` method returned:

```
eat
apple
ie
```

while I expected it to return:

```
eatay
appleay
iepay
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Your iterating over the words, and calling pig() on each word, but you are not store the result. On each iteration the result of calling pig() are discarded. Try adding the items to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your method `translate` is simply iterating over your words and not storing the result. The `map` method stores the result of each iteration and returns an array. If you then join that array back together with a space you'll get a returned string of pig latin.

```
def translate(english)
  english.split(' ').map(&method(:pig)).join(' ')
end
```

Comment: `.map(&method(:pig))` would be a point-free way to express that.

Comment: @sawa it doesn't what?

Comment: @sawa just fired it up in irb with OP's pig method and it runs fine per the "eat apple pie" example and others. What issue are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a destructive method `slice!` in your implementation of `pig`, which may cause unexpected results for beginners. That is related to why you are getting `"ie"` (instead of `"pie"`) in your results. Until you become a more advanced Ruby user, you should keep away from the destructive methods on `String`. Here, use `slice` instead.

It is not a step that you are missing. It is the case that you are using the wrong method. You should use `map` instead of `each` in `translate`.

But besides that, your `translate` method is still unnatural. A more natural code, which returns a string instead of an array, would be:

```
def translate(str)
  str.gsub(/\w+/){|s| pig(s)}
end
```